# Java ExecutorService JDBC connection timeout

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, executorservice

I am making use of an ExecutorService in a server side spring bean. The problem I think is that when the ExecutorService creates the thread/s for the pool, it then also takes a DB connection from the connection pool(C3P0) and then doesn't release it and after a while the connection times out. If I start my server then all works swimmingly for a while, but then after the weekend here is the exception:

```
2012-07-09 11:12:10,825 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] : The last packet successfully received from the server was259505 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 259505 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    at za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl.getUnpaidLeaveForms(ebff4f5 --------------:166)
    at za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl.access$300(ebff4f5 --------------:37)
    at za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl$2.run(ebff4f5 --------------:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2319)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2268)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    ... 6 more
```

Why is my thread not releasing the connection when execution is complete?

Comment: You're using a simple ThreadPoolExecutor? It must be you who creates then passes the connection I guess, so it should be you who releases it after some time.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have anything to do with `ExecutorService` and it's threads: connection testing is configured in c3p0 connection pool configurations. Could you please post part, where c3p0 connection pool is configured?

Comment: Concerning `Why is my thread not releaseing the connection when execution is complete?`: are you invoking `Connection.close` method on connections, when they are no longer needed in thread?

Comment: Could you please as well post part of code, where connections are taken from pool and where they are/should be returned to the pool?

Comment: The above problem doesn't mean that connections are not released to the pool. It means that you're trying to use a connection that was open a long time ago and that has been closed by the server due to a long inactivity. You should configure your connection pool to test the connections before giving them.